# Implement MassTransit replacing ServiceHost and WCF to initiate service

Tags: .net, autofac, masstransit

I have to implement Autofac with MassTransit, for now watching some documentation and tutorials I was able to implement some places in my project, but I am having trouble implementing in this part of my project. I work with WCF.

The following method is an implementation of an interface initializes one of my services, I declare 2 ServiceHost variables type, I initialize them and open the service. The requirement is to perform the same process with MassTransit and MassTransit.Autofac.

```
    private ServiceHost host;
    private ServiceHost utilHost;

    public void StartService()
    {
        host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TeamTimeManager));
        utilHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TeamTimeUtilityManager));

        source.TraceInformation("Start service...");
        host.Open();
        source.TraceInformation("service Started!");

        utilSource.TraceInformation("Starting Utility service...");
        utilHost.Open();
        utilSource.TraceInformation("Utility Service Started!");

        foreach(SettingsProperty item in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
        {
            source.TraceInformation("Service SIP... " + item.Name + " : " + item.DefaultValue);
        }
    }
```

What I'm working on now... it is not initializing any of the 2 services, I tried different ways, but it still does not work, it does not give me any error, just the service does not start, so the implementation must not be correct, how should the implementation be applied in this case?

```
    public void StartService()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.AddMassTransit(
            config =>
            {
                config.AddConsumers(typeof(TeamTimeManager), typeof(TeamTimeUtilityManager));
            });

        var container = builder.Build();

        var bc = container.Resolve<IBusControl>();
        bc.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't configured the bus, which explains why it isn't working. In fact, there is no way that the `IBusControl` interface resolved, given you haven't configured it.

I'd suggest following the [getting started](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/) content, particularly the parts where the actual bus is configured via *UsingInMemory* (or *UsingRabbitMq* if using RabbitMQ).